# Android edittext attributes

Tags: java, android

I have 2 edittext fields in an app.

Depending on which radio button is selected one of these fields is disabled.

The problem is that when the top field is enabled the user types in a double and then there is no option to be "done" with the keyboard because it still considers that the next field needs to be filled in even though it's disabled.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the imeOptions and singleLine attributes in your EditText.

```
<EditText 
   ...
   android:imeOptions="actionDone"
   android:singleLine="true" />
```